# Permission Denied within Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

First of all thanks again for getting me this far. This question is different than my first.

I keep receiving a permission denied. This script has rwx for everyone. It is happening with the `cat /etc/*-release`

I am sure there is something that I am missing.

```
current_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
close_distro=`cat /etc/*-release | grep "^ID_LIKE=" | grep -E -o "[a-z]\w+"`
```

`echo current_distro`
`echo close_distro`

Comment: Yes, you're missing $( ) around your commands. :)

Comment: the original post used backticks rather than $(), and they were interpreted as markup.

Comment: Have you tried `ls -l /etc/*-release`, and can you confirm the permissions on all of those files?

Comment: And those of the parent directory ...

Comment: The permissions for *-release were both 644. I changed them to 755 and the permission denied is no longer being thrown. Not sure if that would be best practice to change the permissions of *-release.It does print current_distro and close_distro though.

Comment: Added the back ticks and "$" in the correct spots. Thank you very much for the help. Another step closer.